# How calibrate logistic regression output probabilites?

Tags: regression, logistic, scikit-learn, matlab, calibration

Based on this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) we can calibrate `logistic regression` (besides other classification models) output probabilities. What is the procedure and steps to do that? I thought that it is only for other classificaiton models such as `SVM` or `random forest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the document you linked:

> LogisticRegression returns well calibrated predictions by default as it directly optimizes log-loss.

So there is generally no need to calibrate logistic regression, the model structure automatically calibrates it to the training data.

On the other hand, if you have a logistic regression model for which you expect the *odds ratios* to be valid for your problem, but possibly not the *overall probabilities*, then you can calibrate a logistic model a new dataset using the techniques in that article.

The situation in the prior paragraph crops up, at least approximately, in business settings where it is expensive to implement a totally new model in production, but cheap to change only a simple part (i.e. an intercept term).  This is common in actuarial work.

Comment: What does "well calibrated" mean here? I have plenty of logistic regression models that I would not call well calibrated. Does it just mean "optimal calibration"?